# Jquery drag and drop realtime with websocket: error when many people drag at the same time

Tags: jquery, websocket, drag-and-drop, real-time

I'm using jquery drag, drop with websocket. When user drag drop item, it will automatically update on other user screens. Like this video: https://youtu.be/JHndS1ps_f0

Library i'm using to drag and drop is: https://github.com/AshesOfOwls/jquery.shapeshift

Basically, the code structure of the drag part is like this:

```
   if (options.enableDrag) {
        $(".item").draggable({
            start: function (e, ui) {
                $selected = $(e.target);
            },
            drag: function (e, ui) {
                //st code with $selected

            },
            stop: function () {
                //st code with $selected
            }
        });
    }
```

But, when I'm during drag, other users also drag + drop, now I continue to drag and drop will fail. variable $selected is undifined. It seems to have been reset.

Comment: Please explain why this is a Go question.

Comment: I'm using golang to develop. But apparently this question is not necessary to it, so I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
if (options.enableDrag) {
        $(".item").draggable({
            start: function (e, ui) {
                $selected = $(e.target);
            },
            drag: function (e, ui) {
                $selected = $(e.target);
                //st code with $selected
            },
            stop: function () {
                //st code with $selected
                $selected = $(e.target);
            }
        });
    }
```